# EC2 Instance Unresponsive After GLIBC Library Update

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang, glibc

When I tried to install erlang for rabbitMQ, it reported an error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by erlang-26.1-1.el8.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by erlang-26.1-1.el8.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) is needed by erlang-26.1-1.el8.x86_64
    libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.7.1)(64bit) is needed by erlang-26.1-1.el8.x86_64
```

And I found solutions on Google and it said the version of glibc needs to update, and I followed these steps:
Use yum to update installation dependencies

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gcc make -y
```

Download rpm packages and install

```
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-utils-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-static-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-common-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-devel-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/glibc-headers-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
wget http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/mosquito/myrepo-el6/epel-6-x86_64/glibc-2.17-55.fc20/nscd-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm &
sudo rpm -Uvh *-2.17-55.el6.x86_64.rpm --force --nodeps
```

Then I removed those packages because I thought they were useless after installation

```
rm -rf glibc-*
```

Then I found a serious problem that my EC2 couldn't exute many command, included wget, sudo

```
sudo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by sudo)
sudo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by /usr/libexec/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0)
```

I used `strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC` and GLIBC_2.26 is not in it.
[image]

But before I excuted those commands wget and sudo could be used.
And soon, I couldn't use ssh to connect this ec2, I thought there had a relation with it.

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

I am wondering whether the bug was caused by me deleting certain RPM packages or by me running those commands that led to the previous version being overwritten. Now, I am attempting to re-download glibc 2.26, but I can't use wget anymore. I tried using yum to download wget, but even yum is not working.
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

```
   /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /lib64/libcrypt.so.1)
```

The issue has become quite severe, to the point where I am unable to use my EC2 instance at all. Can you help me restore my EC2 instance to its previous working state?

Comment: This is unfortunately not on topic here and should be asked on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), but in general it is never safe to upgrade glibc without upgrading the OS.  If you do that, things will generally be broken, as you've found.  That would also not fix the problems you were seeing.

Comment: You "installed" GLIBC-2.17 on a system which _requires_ GLIBC-2.26, rendering your system inoperational and unbootable. Don't do _that_. You will now have to completely re-install this system.